# OpenType Latex font for usage in text editor

Tags: greek, opentype

I like to use the LaTeX fonts as well in text editors. Concerning this, some questions came into my mind:

1. Is it true that I need so called OpenType fonts for that, which I could use like Times or Arial etc.?
2. I do have, from my TeX distribution, fonts called "Latin Modern Roman" in various forms (slanted, italic, bold, ...). Do I have the right ones?
3. Finally, I want to do some mathematical characters like `\omega`, `\hbar` and so on. I found hbar which in italic looks similar to the one produced with LaTeX. But omega seems to be replaced by the Lucida font. Do I need an additional font for Greek Latex OpenType?

To be more precise, I would like to be able to use Word or Pages with the same font that Latex does, which is Computer Modern or Latin Modern, I am not quite sure. I do have the OpenType fonts of them, but when I compare `\hbar \omega` from a compiled Latex document to what Pages gives me, it will yield the following (first the Latex, afterwards the Pages result):
[image]
[image]

Again, I want to be able to have the Latex result reproduced with Pages.

Comment: Try the [CMU](http://canopus.iacp.dvo.ru/~panov/cm-unicode/) fonts. They cover Greek and Cyrillic as well.

Comment: Use the Latin Modern with Latin Modern Math. Both are available for unicode

Comment: @Herbert I finally found it. But there is not an italic font included. Do you know if it is available somewhere?

Comment: @DaPhil: http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm  shows all fonts

Comment: But there is not math font...

Answer (score 4):

The layout of the characters in classic TeX fonts is somewhat eccentric (For example capital Greek gamma is in position **0** in the Roman font. Thus it is not automatic (to say the least) that typing any non-ASCII character in a text editor will directly produce the same character when typeset by TeX.

If you use utf8 encoding

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Or use xelatex or lualatex (which are natively utf-8 based Unicode systems) and you use OpenType versions of fonts such as the latin modern collection then you are in a better position to see similar characters. For mathematics though you probably would want `unicode-math` (which only works with lualetex or xelatex).

Perhaps you need to be more specific about the TeX variants and Editors and kind of input you want.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I don't want to use opentype in latex editors. I want to use the tex font computer modern in editors such as Word or Pages. I think phg's comment under my question is more was I am searching but not 100% so I will update my question with some figures later.

Comment: @DaPhil You can not use the original computer modern fonts in non TeX systems for encoding and other reasons, they are not encoded in a way designed for direct keyboard input the math fonts assume you will be entered via TeX commands

Comment: I am confused. You are saying it is not possible, Herbert (comment on my question) says it is possible. I actually think that Latin Modern Math is the font I am searching...

Comment: @DaPhil Herbet's comment matches this answer. Latin Modern is available for Unicode which means you can get them to work in editors and other applications but (especially for the math fonts) unicode encoded fonts are no use in classic TeX, which is why in this answer I suggested that if you go that route you probably want to use xetex or luatex and the unicode-math package.